# Angular Unit Test - Error Injection Message

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Attempting to write a Unit Test in Angular 8 while utilizing WebStorm. Have debugged and still receiving error message that does not allow unit test to be built. Need assistance. Below is the code that I have and then I provide the error message being given.

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { SessionService } from './session.service';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]), MatMenuModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [SessionService],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'apTime'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('apTime');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span').textContent).toContain('apTime app is running!');
  });
});
```

Error message being given:

```
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> AmplifyService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AmplifyService!

error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'AppComponent', Function ], ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 33603585, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 49152, directChildFlags: 49152, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 1, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'app-root', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent: <circular reference: Object>, renderParent: <circular reference: Object>, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 1, flags: 49152, childFlags: 0, directChildFlags: 0, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object, matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object, ngContentIndex: -1,  ...
    at <Jasmine>
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:855:1)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30393:1)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31578:1)
    at resolveDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:32143:1)
```

Comment: have you tried adding AmplifyService to your providers array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your AmplifyService in the providers array.

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]), MatMenuModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        SessionService, 
        AmplifyService
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```